# Did wrong. Btc to Ltc from Trezor

Tags: blockchain, litecoin, trezor

Accidentally/stupidly sent Btc to Ltc address. 
On my Trezor I generated a Btc 'send payment', then I generated a 'receive payment'. Trezor asked for the Ltc address to be converted, which I did, then I pasted it and confirmed the lot...all steps done from my Trezor...I did wrong, because I forgot an important step, to convert the transaction on sites like Changelly before carrying on with the confirmation...The transaction is on the blockchain and the continuous rising number of confirmations indicate, at least to me, that it has been accepted. So, the funds are sitting on the blockchain in limbo! Is there anything I can do to retrieve the funds? 
Cheers

Comment: How did you send Bitcoin to a Litecoin address? Bitcoin and Litecoin uses different addresses that are incompatible with each other.